# jQuery Missing Parenthesis on function causes Cross-Orgin Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I forgot `()` on the jQuery `val` function but received a strange error and am wondering what the cause of that was.

I had the following code:

```
$('#element').on('focusout', function() {
    $.post("/ajax", 
        {
            email: $('#email').val,
        }
    );
});
```

and received:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

It seems like my syntax error must have been executing something else.

This is a static HTML page, no `iframe`, `frame` or any content hosted on another domain/subdomain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: @Tân No, I'm not using frames. All on `example.com`.